# Is a composition of two $n-1$-dimensional symmetries a composition of $n-2$-dimensional symmetries?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional real Euclidean space and $S,T$ be symmetries with respect to $n-1$-dimensional subspaces of $X$.

Is it possible to write $ST$ as a composition of  symmetries with respect to $(n-2)$-dimensional subspaces of $X$ ?How to do it?

Edit

A mapping $S:X\rightarrow X$ we call a symmetry if $S$ is linear and $S^2=Id$.
If the set of all fixed points of $S$ is  $Y$ we say that $S$ is a symmetry with respect to (a linear subspace) $Y$.

For arbitrary symmetry $S$ we have that $X$ is a prime sum of two orthogonal subspaces $X=Y+Z,$ where $Y=\{s\in X: Sx=x\}$, $Z=\{x\in X: Sx=-x\}$.
Then 
$$
S(y+z)=y-z \textrm{ for } y\in Y, z\in Z.
$$

Comment: So in this case $S$ and $T$ would each leave an $n-1$-dimensional subspace of $X$ invariant?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more precise about what you mean by symmetries with respect to subspaces. If a symmetry w.r.t. a subspace Y is any isometry of X that fixes each point in Y (e.g. reflections in Y or rotations around Y) then the answer is yes, assuming that n is the dimension of X and not just any number. When S and T fix n-1 dimensional subspaces Y_S and Y_T then their composition ST fixes the intersection of Y_S and Y_T which (in case n = dim X) is an (n-2) dimensional subspace and so with the above definition we can say that ST actually IS a symmetry w.r.t such a subspace

Comment: (above is not really true when Y_S = Y_T but if n = dim X this can only happen if ST = identity)